# Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable and $Z$ be a random variable taking values $\{-1,1\}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable and $Z$ be a random variable taking values $\{-1,1\}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$

Let $Y=XZ$, determine whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

As
it turns out $Y$ will also be a standard normal random variable. For independence I am getting hung up on. If they are independent then we will have

$P(X \le y, Y \le y) = P(X \le y)P(Y \le y)$

I am not quite convinced of either independence nor dependence.

I am trying to write it as $P(X \le y, Y \le y) = P(X \le y)P(Y \le y \mid X \le y) = P(Y \le y)P(X \le y \mid Y \le y) $

Which then I can condition further on the value of $Z$ but it seems maybe it is possible to see it without conditioning that far.

Comment: What is $P(-1/2 < Y < 1/2)$?  What is $P(X > 1)$?  What is $P(-1/2 < Y < 1/2, X > 1)$?

Comment: Dependent. If $Y=0$ then $X=0$. If $Y=1$ then $X=\pm 1$ with equal probabilities. Had they been independent, knowing $Y$ would not imply anything about $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $y <0$ you have

$$P(X <y )=P(Y <y ) \lt \frac12$$

and

$$P(X \le y, Y \le y) = P(X \le y,Z=1) \\= P(X \le y)P(Z=1) = P(X \le y) \times \frac12 \\> P(X <y )P(Y <y )$$

Comment: Nicely done! I knew it had to be simpler than what I was trying to do.

Comment: Is Y independent to Z? How to prove it?

Comment: @user98694q87 Probably easiest to find whether $P(Z=z \mid Y=y)=P(Z=z)$ or not, for all $y$ and $z$

Comment: Thank you!! My proof tells me Y and Z are independent using your idea, but I am not that sure about this result. Since Y is composed of Z, why they can be independent? Intuition makes me confused.

Comment: @user98694q87 $Y$ and $Z$ are indeed independent and I find this intuitive: if you told me $Y$ but not $X$ then I would have no idea about $Z$.

Comment: Oh! Got it! Thank you for your clarification.